# Django: UnicodeEncodeError when trying to save non-ascii text

Tags: django, unicode

I am trying to save a new record with some unicode text in one of the fields.

Saving the unicode text is successful when using the django admin page, but when using the django shell fails with:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any ideas what's wrong and how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in your model's __unicode__ method. You should post that and the traceback.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting `u` before the string you are working with.

```
print "ЙЦУКЕН"; #error!
print u"ЙЦУКЕН"; #success!
```

Comment: +1 for Silver Light. Point of note - in Python 3, all strings are unicode by default. However, in older versions of Python, you must specifically mark a string literal as an unicode string (as Silver Light has shown above).

Comment: I'm not printing the string, I'm trying to save a django model which has this unicode string inside one of its columns. The `u` is totally irrelevant here.

Comment: @Gj: Then post the full traceback.

Answer (score 2):

these handy django build-in conversion functions often do the trick for me. I use them for generating pdfs with special characters.

[utility conversion functions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#conversion-functions)

for saving non-ascii text in your model:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode

mymodel.my_field = smart_unicode(myform.cleaned_data["my_non_ascii_text"])
mymodel.save()
```

Comment: Since Django 1.5 it's been renamed to `smart_text`.